# I would like to display data from a database in an MVC project using sql adapter

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, view, sqldatareader

I am looking to use the SQL Data adapter feature inside of MVC to display the results from a query string inside of my project. I'm new to using the sql adapter feature but I would like to get used to it. Simply put, I need to know what to put in my controller, and if i need to create a model, and what to put in my view.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Mvc;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
 using System.Configuration;


 namespace NewHoyaIntranet.Controllers
 {
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        DataSet data;
        DataTable table;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new 



  SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HUT"]
  .ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM HUT.dbo.XREF_HIOI_LensStyle_HTL", connection);

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = select;

            data = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(data, "HUT.dbo.XREF_HIOI_LensStyle_HTL");

            table = data.Tables[0]; //is the [0] really correct?
        }

        return View(/* Right now nothing is returning in any view/ how do i tie the view in? */);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: It is called model-view-controller. Where is the model(s) here? What is the view expected to receive?

Comment: `SqlAdapter` has very little to do with this. You really need to learn how MVC works, and we can't teach you that in an SO question. https://www.asp.net/learn

Comment: I know how mvc works crowcoder. I use it ever day. do you know how to use the sql adapter tool? If not, don't comment. I told you in my original post that i have not created a model yet because I am unsure how to use it.

Comment: Steve, the view is expected to receive the data through the select query. I simply want to display queries in mvc

Comment: So no _@model IEnumerable<yourModelClassHere>_ as the first line of the View?

Comment: In fact I do know how to use ADO.Net. At a glance, it appears that you do too. So I guess your question is how to populate a Model from a DataSet or a DataTable. Your question is very unclear and I meant no offense.

Comment: @ Crowcoder   Yes I believe that the model would be the next thing that needs to be created before I move on to the view. I've seen things both on view models and models but i guess the simplest way to do this would be the latter.  This is what I have right now in my model which is basically nothing.

Comment: namespace NewHoyaIntranet.Models
{
    public class Test
    {


            };
        }

Comment: @ steve, I've seen an example where that would be the case but I think i should be working on the model before I do the view. The view will take references from the model. Is this correct or am i going about it all wrong?

Comment: Well, of course, the view is supposed to display the model. So until you have defined your model... But, how did you build the Controller? If you have used the Visual Studio scaffolding interface you need to select the model to use with the Controller and the related Views (the usual stuff Index, Details,Create, Delete, Edit)

Comment: However, your problem is to define the class for your model and then get the data from the dataset to build an IEnumerable of your class. After that you return the IEnumerable to the View (This is what makes so handy EF or any other ORM in this context )

Comment: Side note. If you want your comments to reach my inbox don't put a space between the @ and the name.

Comment: @steve I've got to take a break for today, maybe we can chat tommorow. I  'll have to creat the empty model tommorow with the usual stuff. When I had use the scaffolding interface to build the model, how then do I get the data from the dataset to build the class. I get that the view will be pretty simple, it's the model that I'm worried about

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141455/discussion-between-evan-and-steve).